# Sysgic Fleet IntegXamarinDemo3D - won't get GPS fix

Tags: c#, android, embedded, fleet, sygic

I compiled the Sygic Fleet example "IntegXamarinDemo3D" with Visual Studio 2019.

I am running it on a Samsung Galaxy T2 tablet running Android 7.

What works as designed including getting a GPS signal:

1. Sygic app for Android.
2. Sygic Truck app for Android.
3. The Java example apps that come with the Sygic Fleet SDK
4. Any other app using GPS

What doesn't:

1. This sample app, "IntegXamarinDemo3D", once compiled, starts up as designed, shows the map, and all functions work **BUT** Sygic shows *"No GPS signal"* and "Navigate" requests what to use as a starting GPS location. The apps mentioned above have no problem nor does Google Location Services which I use in several apps including my own embedded Sygic app which also shows the "No GPS Signal" problem.

Since the same Sygic library appears to be used with all the examples, this seems to have something to do with the processing of the SygicLib.aar to SygicBindings.dll during the VS 2019 compilation but I can't find what it is.

My whole app design on the Embedded support in Sygic Fleet, Android, C#, and VS2019.

Has anyone encountered this, or better, have any idea how to fix it.

Jim

Answer (score 0):

After a couple weeks of searching and trying things, I found the solution this morning by looking inside SygicLib.aar at AndroidManilfest.xml.

In the application AndroidManifest.xml, I had to insert the following line just prior to the other  lines.

```
<service android:name="com.sygic.aura.feature.gps.LocationService"/>
```

Jim